# switchMap для единственного роута

Tags: javascript, angular2, angular4, angular5, rxjs

При клике на кнопку срабатывает метод getDatafromServer.
Подскажите, правильно ли в Angular реализован switchMap для одного роута т.е. при повторном нажатии отменяется предыдущий запрос (если еще не пришел старый) и отправляется новый:

```
  getDatafromServer() {
    of(`url1`).pipe(switchMap(url => this.httpGeneralService.getDataFromJsonServer(url))).
      subscribe(i => console.log(i));
}
```

Вроде все верно, но в браузере в Network не видно, чтобы отменялись предыдущие запросы

UPD: похоже этот вариант рабочий:

```
  private requestPasswordSubject$ = new Subject();

  private requestPassword = this.requestPasswordSubject$.pipe(
    switchMap(() => this.httpGeneralService.getDataFromJsonServer(`url1`))
  )
    .subscribe(response => { console.log(response); } );

  getDatafromServer() {
    this.requestPasswordSubject$.next();
}
```

Comment: откуда предположение, что должен отменяться предыдущий запрос?

Comment: switchMap делает complete для предыдущего Observable

Comment: а какой, в данном случае, у тебя _предыдущий_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`switchMap` будет работать правильно в том случае, если события по нажатию на кнопку будут идти из потока. В данном случае:

```
of(`url1`).pipe(switchMap(url => this.httpGeneralService.getDataFromJsonServer(url)))
```

`of('url1')` - это холодный поток, который сгенерирует событие 1 раз и закроется (вопрос зачем вы так делаете?) Я бы сказал это бесполезный код.

Если вы хотите по клику на кнопку отправлять запрос и отписываться от потока, если не пришел ответ, но пришло новое событие - нужно использовать связку `fromEvent + switchMap`:

```
const button = document.querySelector('button');

fromEvent(button, 'click').pipe(
  switchMap(() => this.httpGeneralService.getDataFromJsonServer(`url1`))
).subscribe((response) => {
  console.log(response);
});
```

`switchMap` подписывается на поток `fromEvent`, параметром принимает фабрику (в концепции RxJS это называется проекция), вызывает эту фабрику и результатом получает новый поток (который возвращает `this.httpGeneralService.getDataFromJsonServer('url1')`), подписывается на этот поток, ждет ответа, если `fromEvent` сгенерирует событие раньше чем поток `getDataFromJsonServer` - `SwitchMapSubscriber` отписывается от `getDataFromJsonServer` и обрабатывает новое поступившее событие из потока `fromEvent`.

```
 _next(value) {
    let result;
    const index = this.index++;
    try {
        result = this.project(value, index); // вызвали проекцию и получили поток
    }
    catch (error) {
        this.destination.error(error);
        return;
    }
    this._innerSub(result, value, index);
}
_innerSub(result, value, index) {
    const innerSubscription = this.innerSubscription;
    if (innerSubscription) {
        innerSubscription.unsubscribe(); // отписываемся от предыдущей проекции
    }
}
```